# Want to run the code from the paper "first return, then explore" from Uber AI and Open AI. Can't install python library tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, installation

I have installed Python 3.6.6 on my Windows 10 PC.

I also created an extra environment for the project, but if I try to install the libraries the following error occurs:

```
(frte_pb_1) C:\\Users\\Elias\\Downloads\\go-explore-master\\policy_based\>pip install -r requirements.txt

Collecting tensorflow==1.15.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.15.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions: )

No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.15.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
```

The requirements.txt have listed the following libraries:

```
tensorflow==1.15.2
mpi4py
gym\[Atari\]
horovod
baselines@git+https://github.com/openai/baselines@ea25b9e8b234e6ee1bca43083f8f3cf974143998
Pillow
imageio
matplotlib
loky
joblib
dataclasses
opencv-python
cloudpickle
```

And the code I got from:

https://github.com/uber-research/go-explore

Previously I had an newer Python version installed, but in the Readme of the creator it was noticed that the code was tested with Python 3.6 so I installed Python 3.6, but it did not help, then I tried a few different Python Versions and now im with 3.6.6 and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There is no tensorflow version 1.15.2.

https://www.tensorflow.org/versions

That git repo calls for 1.5.2.  Both Python 3.6 and tensorflow 1.5.2 are quite old; you may be in for some discomfort.